# Condition shell comparison don't work

Tags: shell, conditional-statements

```
data=$(wget -qO - https://blockchain.info/fr/q/addressbalance/$pk)
if [$data != 0]; then
    echo "Hello"
else
    echo "good bye"
fi
```

I have tried a lot of possibilities. I don't know how to work this.

I don't understand why this condition doesn't work.

`wget -qO - https://blockchain.info/fr/q/addressbalance/$pk
if [$? != 0]; then
    echo "Hello"
else
    echo "good bye"
fi`

> Result: `192005332305./btc.sh: ligne 6: [0 : commande introuvable
>   good bye`

Comment: BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ would have caught this for you automatically without getting humans involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command does not return the errorcode, use $?

```
wget -qO - https://blockchain.info/fr/q/addressbalance/$pk
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    echo "Hello"
else
    echo "good bye"
fi
```

You should have space inside the bracket.

Here my code for test, works perfekt:

```
wget -qO - $1 > test.txt
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    echo "Hello"
else
    echo "good bye"
fi
```

Comment: I have try this $? and it work. But i have always this error :
./mybtc.sh: ligne 6: [0 : commande introuvable

Comment: Sorry, did not saw the second problem.

Comment: I have all time the error ./mybtc.sh: ligne 6: [0 : commande introuvable
Ligne 6 is if [$? != 0]; then

Comment: the  var pk is `pk=$(sed -n '1p' wall.txt)`

Comment: it's my fault working now ! thx a lot

Comment: No don't work, all time give hello. not problem i go research again solution ...

Comment: So you file does not exists. Works perfekt here.

Comment: In general, referring to `$?` when you don't need to is bad practice -- use `if ! wget -qO ...` if all you want to do is test for failure.